# Spring Security Core authAjax, How do I ignore the Referer

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication, grails, spring-security

I'm using Grails 1.3.7 and the latest spring-security-core plugin.  I've implemented the following method in my LoginController:

```
def authAjax = {
   response.setHeader 'Location', SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.auth.ajaxLoginFormUrl
   response.sendError HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED
}
```

And in my global JavaScript file, I have the following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      if (xhr.status == 401) {
         // display a login form in a dialog
      }
   }
});
```

The login form is the standard login form directly from the plugin documentation.  The only difference is I submit my form using jQuery like so:

```
var params = $('#ajaxLoginForm').serialize();
$.post($('#ajaxLoginForm').attr('action'), params, function(jsonData) {
   if (jsonData.success) {
      $('#login-dialog').dialog('close');
   } else {
      alert('TODO: display errors');
   }
}, 'json');
```

The problem is that the first time I click the login button, I seem to be authenticating ok, but the response coming back from the server is a 302 redirect based on the Referer request header.  So the body of my $.post() never gets ran.  I'm getting HTML back instead of JSON.  It doesn't actually hit my LoginController.ajaxSuccess method until the second submission.  I've read and re-read the documentation and I must be missing something.

UPDATE: It looks like it might not be a Referer issue, since the second time the form is posted, the Referer is still there.  So I'm at a complete loss as to why I have to submit the form twice for the ajaxSuccess method to get called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you make an un-authorized attempt to access a protected resource, Spring Security saves that request on your session (http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/DefaultSavedRequest.html), and then when you successfully authenticate, it redirects you to that request.  You can probably turn this behavior off across the board with Spring Security configuration, but that's probably not what you want for most workflows.  You could also probably explicitly remove the SavedRequest from the session in your authAjax method, but again, that's probably not the best experience for the user.

I believe LoginController.ajaxSuccess only gets hit if there is no SavedRequest to redirect to insted, so the HTML you're getting back should be the result of your original request, which was un-authorized at the time. So, the trick is you want to use whatever function you would have used to process the original request as the success method on your #ajaxLoginForm submission.

Comment: Micah,  thanks for you answer.  For the most part, I believe you are correct. However, there is nothing about this in the spring-security-core docs nor is any of this mentioned in the 2 screencasts, specifically the 2nd screencast which covers this exact scenario.  So there has to either be a bug or something I'm missing, or I suppose something the tutorial isn't stating explicitly.

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as correct unless someone comes along with a less hacked solution.  Basically, in the authAjax method, I did the following: session.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY = null.  Now it works as expected.

Comment: Hi I am facing a similar issue, when session is terminated, authAjax is sending 401 error if I click any link inside the terminated session screen, Instead I need to forward the user to login screen, how did you achieve this? I tried the hack, do I need to add the global js redirect?

Comment: Also what is the final content in authAjax

Answer (score 0):

Gregg, you're probably hitting default servlet container behaviour for 401 responses. I recommend you use something like:

```
def authAjax = {
    response.setHeader 'Location', SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.auth.ajaxLoginFormUrl
    render status: 401, contentType: "application/json", {
    message = "You are not authorized for this page"
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it, so let me know how it goes.

Comment: That doesn't change the behavior was I was experiencing.  And when I look at the response in Firebug from authAjax, I don't see the json.  I do see that the contentType was set correctly, but the message never comes across.