# Spring Security ajax login interpreted as regular login request (not AJAX)

Tags: jquery, grails, spring-security

I'm trying to make a login form with Grails / Spring Security Core. The request is apparently correct but instead of behaving like an ajax login request, it's handled as a regular login request (IE redirected to the default login url instead of ajaxSuccess). This makes is clearer:

[image]

My request should be redirected to authAjax and then to ajaxSuccess because I'm using the correct password, actually, if I refresh the web site, I'm now logged in, it's just not redirecting me to the correct action on the login controller. This is the code for my authAjax action:

```
def authAjax = {
    session.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY = null
    response.setHeader 'Location', SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.auth.ajaxLoginFormUrl
    response.sendError HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding the following line to the action that render the view that contains the ajax form:
session.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY = null

You can find more details on why this solves the problem on the following link:
[Spring Security Core authAjax, How do I ignore the Referer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628199/spring-security-core-authajax-how-do-i-ignore-the-referer?rq=1)